# Add network location via command line/batch in windows xp/vista/7?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, network-shares

I need to provide an accessible way for blind users to upload lots or small - or single large - files to me. I can't find an ftp client that can be easily preconfigured for each user, so mapping a network <strike>drive</strike> location to ftp seemed to be easiest.

Easy via the GUI of course, but the GUI new share wizard doesn't help blind people, even with screenreaders.

I thought I was close with the [MS net commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx), and this [Superuser answer mentioning pushd](https://superuser.com/questions/52220/how-do-i-connect-to-a-network-share-via-the-windows-command-prompt) which is new to me and potentially useful, but I can't seem to marry the whole lot up.

In short, it needs to be as simple as possible for a user, logged into the web page (which knows their ftp details) to be able to click link, download app, and press "go" to upload all files from a certain folder to the ftp server using their login. The more accessible the better. Thanks.